# Why was my last AT command routine is not viewed in the output?

Tags: gpio, python, pigpio, gsm, bit-bang

As I was using pigpio ,so that I can use the GPIO pins as UART or bit banging the serial. I am using a SIM900 gsm module. Here is the code:

```
import pigpio
import time
import sys

TX=23
RX=18
baudrate=9600
bytesize=8

try:
    pi = pigpio.pi()
    pi.set_mode(RX, pigpio.INPUT)
    pi.set_mode(TX, pigpio.OUTPUT)

    pi.exceptions=False
    pi.bb_serial_read_close(RX)
    pi.exceptions=True

    pi.bb_serial_read_open(RX, baudrate, bytesize)

    pi.wave_add_new()
    pi.wave_add_serial(TX,9600,'AT\r',8)
    wid = pi.wave_create()
    pi.wave_send_once(wid)
    pi.wave_delete(wid)
    (count, data) = pi.bb_serial_read(RX)
    if count:
        print data
    time.sleep(1.5)

    pi.wave_add_new()
    pi.wave_add_serial(TX,9600,'AT+CPIN?\r',8)
    wid = pi.wave_create()
    pi.wave_send_once(wid)
    pi.wave_delete(wid)
    (count, data) = pi.bb_serial_read(RX)
    if count:
        print data
    time.sleep(1.5)

    pi.wave_add_new()
    pi.wave_add_serial(TX,9600,'AT+CIPSHUT\r',8)
    wid = pi.wave_create()
    pi.wave_send_once(wid)
    pi.wave_delete(wid)
    (count, data) = pi.bb_serial_read(RX)
    if count:
        print data
    time.sleep(1.5)

    pi.wave_add_new()
    pi.wave_add_serial(TX,9600,"AT+CIPMUX=0\r",8)
    wid = pi.wave_create()
    pi.wave_send_once(wid)
    pi.wave_delete(wid)
    (count, data) = pi.bb_serial_read(RX)
    if count:
        print data
    time.sleep(1.5)

    pi.wave_add_new()
    pi.wave_add_serial(TX,9600,"AT+CGATT=1\r",8)
    wid = pi.wave_create()
    pi.wave_send_once(wid)
    pi.wave_delete(wid)
    (count, data) = pi.bb_serial_read(RX)
    if count:
        print data + '\n'
    time.sleep(1.5)

    pi.wave_add_new()
    pi.wave_add_serial(TX,9600,"AT\r",8)
    wid = pi.wave_create()
    pi.wave_send_once(wid)
    pi.wave_delete(wid)
    (count, data) = pi.bb_serial_read(RX)
    if count:
        print data
    time.sleep(1.5)

except:
    pi.bb_serial_read_close(RX)
    pi.stop()
```

I think the problem is with the delay of outputting.

output is :

```
>>> 
AT

OK

AT+CPIN?

+CPIN: READY

OK

AT+CIPSHUT

SHUT OK

AT+CIPMUX=0

OK


AT+CGATT=1

OK

>>>
```

it skips the last AT command which is a simple "AT"(even if I delete that command, all in the last command will not be displayed). Can someone help me?.